# Data Manipulation in accordance with a Pattern in Python

Tags: python-2.7

The Problem statement deals with Data time Series Generation in the Format : [(datavalue1,datetime1),(datavalue2,datetime2),(datevalue3,datetime3),....]

Now, Following are the inputs required from the user:
(a.) No of values to be generated in the series.
(b.) Datetime1 to be given by the user in "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" format or can be taken locally as current time from machine.
(c.) Time interval between two datetime values.
(d.) Maximum and Minimum data value from which a random value to be taken as "DataValue1".
(e.) Random Pattern from user such as +3+2-1-2 or -3+2 or -1-2+3-4+5 etc.

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
def series(x, pattern):
    pattern = [pattern[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(pattern), 2)]
    start = x
    results = []
    for k in pattern:
        for i in range(5):
            start = eval('start+%s' %(k))
            results.append(start)
    return results
```

This runs as:

```
>>> series(70, "+1+3-2-1")
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 88, 86, 84, 82, 80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75]
```

The above code just uses 4 basic `for` loops to add/subtract the specific values the specified amount of times.

Comment: PATTERN '+1+3-2-1' was just an example.The Pattern can be random i.e. '+3-2' or '-3-2+1+4' or '+3-4+5-6+7' and so on.
Anyways thanks for the effort.I think using an If statement would help.

Comment: thanks.I think this piece of code will help me with little bit of tweaking.